# Rename multiple files with special characters in filenames

Tags: powershell, substring, wildcard, file-rename

Trying to remove the first few characters from a large number of files in the same directory, but having trouble with special characters in the filenames.  I also need to use a wildcard to specify what text to remove since that text may contain a one or two digit number.

I'm a novice using v2.0.1.1.

an example filename is

```
(2) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg
```

I need to remove the initial number in parenthesis along with the following space.  the number in parenthesis may be one or two digits, hence the need for a wildcard.

Resulting filename should be:

```
S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg
```

All files will contain coordinates separated by "," in square brackets, and all will be .jpg, but everything else in the final names names will vary.

Been reading through various articles on bits and pieces of what is going wrong, have tried code below.

Issue seems to be with square brackets and maybe the comma, but only techniques I can find (``[, etc.) tell you how to deal with them in the search string, not in the portion of the string you are uninterested in.  -literalpath does not seem to help, either.

```
dir | rename-item -NewName { ($_.name) -Replace("\(*\) ","")}
```

And have tried various alterations to this basic code.

Runs through every file, but all with:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\...\(2) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg' does not exist.
At line:1 char:19
+ dir | rename-item <<<<  -NewName { ($_.name) -Replace("\(*\) ","")}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for powershell complex scripts, you can do in simple CMD.

This will rename files with 1 length number:

```
for %a in ("(?) *.*") do ren "%a" "////*.*"
```

And this for a 2 length number:

```
for %a in ("(??) *.*") do ren "%a" "/////*.*"
```

you might be tempted to do:

```
for %a in ("(*) *.*") do ren "%a" "////*.*"
```

but then you will end up filenames with spaces at the beginning if they have 2+ length numbers.

How it works ?

Let's first see the rename:
So if you have this filename: `(2) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg`, what we want to do is:

```
ren "(?) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg" "////*.*";
```

The `?` question mark means any one length character.
The `*` asterisk means any **many** characters.
The `/` means discard this one character.

so `(2) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg` => `S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg`

for the 2 length numbers, you will need two ?? and five ///// like this:

```
ren "(??) S17- 22429 E1_[49946,12147]_composite_image.jpg" "/////*.*";
```

We use the space after the `)` so the pattern is matched more strict.

Then we use:

```
for %a in (`condition`) do `command`
```

it iterates for every file in condition and then execute the command. %a is a special wildcard that you can use on the command to get the filename.

so basically, what we do is for each file, rename discarding the first 4 or 5 charaters, and we use the ? in the condition so we get all files that matches the pattern.

and voila, you can also adapt as your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Rename-Item has problems with the special characters indeed. When Cmdlets fail you it is often a good idea to look for object methods. Try this one. It works for me on PS 5.1

```
gci *.jpg | % {
  $_.MoveTo("$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.Name -replace '\(.*\) ','')")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if I do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Filter '*.jpg' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^\(\d+\)\s*', '')}
```

This is assuming the filename always starts with a number between the brackets. If it can be any character (or even nothing) between these brackets, do `($_.Name -replace '^\(.*\)\s*', '')`

---

**EDIT**

Apparently, renaming multiple files through the pipeline needs the syntax for `Rename-Item` to be a script block, as shown in the fourth example in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6#examples).

If you do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\' -Filter '*.jpg' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^\(\d+\)\s*', '' }
```

It works.
So, you almost got it right except for two things:

- you've added round brackets to the `-replace` parameter
- you've added the regex quantifier `*` directly after the opening bracket, so basically your regex asked for zero or more `(` characters instead of whatever is between the brackets in the file name

Hope that helps